# Dynamically add Component to model

Tags: qt, qml

How can I append my dynamically created Qml Object to a ListModel?

I tried this, but it doesn`t work.

```
property ListModel projects
Component.onCompleted: {
    var comp= Qt.createComponent("Project.qml");
    var object = comp.createObject(parent,{});
    projects.append(object);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListModel append(), insert() and set() take a dictionary as their argument. So you will need to wrap the object returned by createObject() into a dictionary.

Also create an instance of the ListModel to assign to projects properties so that you can append to it.

```
property ListModel projects: ListModel {}
Component.onCompleted: {
    var comp= Qt.createComponent("Project.qml");
    var object = comp.createObject(parent, {});
    projects.append({"name": object});
}
```

Comment: "name" property should be unique?How to write a function, which adds to model?

Comment: "name" is unique within one dictionary or ListElement, but you will be appending multiple of these so to uniquely identify them, just add another element to the dictionary like {"id": <unique value>, "name": object} .

Comment: I tried adding without a name and this works.
 var comp= Qt.createComponent("Project.qml");
 var object = comp.createObject(parent,{});
 projects.append(object);